# Maxifs and Sumifs to newest date

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet Balance History with account balances my date/time, along with account name, month and year text fields.

I'm trying to show the most recent balance by account for a specific month and year on a separate (AssetsDebts).  The sumifs &
maxifs formula below does find newest balance by account name and the
Sumifs formula below will sum all rows where the name, month and year
match.  However the combination of the two always results in zero.  My
thought was I could add the 4th criteria ( maxifs ) within the sumifs
and have it work but no luck.

Any help would be great, i am not married to sumifs/maxifs as long as I can reach the above goal.

```
Balance History'!H:H = Balance Total
Balance History'!D:D = Account Name
Balance History'!O:O = Date/Time ( date )
Balance History'!M:M = Month ( text )
Balance History'!N:N = Year ( text )
     
AssetsDebts Sheet
E2 = Account Name
B2 = Month ( text )
C2 = Year ( text )
     
Sumifs & Maxifs
sumifs('Balance History'!H:H,'Balance History'!D:D,E2,'Balance History'!O:O,(maxifs('Balance History'!O:O,'Balance History'!D:D,E2)))
     
Sumifs
sumifs('Balance History'!H:H,'Balance History'!D:D,E2,'Balance History'!M:M,B2,'Balance History'!N:N,C2)
     
Combined (results zero )
sumifs('Balance History'!H:H,'Balance History'!D:D,E2,'Balance History'!M:M,B2,'Balance History'!N:N,C2,'BalanceHistory'!O:O,(maxifs('Balance History'!O:O,'Balance History'!D:D,E2)))
```

Sheet [LINK](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZqoVDUwgjUg8CDneP1yqImnOiMtoZcpGiHLuaDtPOlQ/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Welcome! It would be a great idea to create and share a public Google Sheet with fake data in order to get help.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.  I've updated with a sample sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Query function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) is probably your best bet. If you put the below formula into a cell on you `AssetsDebts` sheet, and have it reference some respective inputs for date/, you'll what you need. Note that there are quotes around the year because the way you've setup your array functions in the history tab has it structured that way.

[Functional sheet here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RBa3v43295HoZOzYAUml4PggmhzUK3pzCCzH-3OhePg/edit#gid=0)

Actual formula: `=Query('Balance History'!B:O,"Select H WHERE G = '"&J4&"' and M = '"&J3&"' and N = '"&J2&"' ORDER BY O DESC Limit 1",0)`

[image]

Comment: I like the idea of the query function thanks.  However I update the sample sheet to put the query in column G and just change the cell references to B, C and E respectively.  However I get this error.   

Query completed with an empty output.

Did I miss something?   I did not think that would change the output.

Comment: It works on the sample sheet I provided. I don't know what you're doing to change it, but the syntax is there.

Comment: @James, the solution provided above does work indeed. It looks like the query you are using does not pass the expected cell values.

Comment: I've found the issue but not quite sure how to fix it.  In column B and C I am using the following formulas to set the Month and Year so each time a line is added I do not need to do it manually.

I deleted this and just typed the month year in and it worked.  In my original post I stated Month and Year were text, which I thought they would be based on the follow.

Any thoughts?

ARRAYFORMULA({"Month";IF(A2:A="",,TEXT(A2:A,"mmmm"))})
ARRAYFORMULA({"Year";IF(A2:A="",,TEXT(A2:A,"mmmm"))})

Comment: Great thanks, sorry to hold up the accept.  Wasn't my intent.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. I'll load it up. Using array formulas is a smart approach, but they can be a little tricky. Give me 5 minutes.

Comment: It also might make your overall situation easier if you combined one column with Year_Month_Account...

Comment: @James, checkout the file i shared. I updated your array columns with different formulas. I think the issue you might need to lookout for is Year being text/number in the columna and your query.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking at the formulas and couldn't figure out the difference.  However I see the I mistyped the array formula above and didn't change mmmm to yyyy.  So I'm still getting the same error Query completed with an empty output in my sample sheet.

Not sure if you have any other thoughts.  thank you for all the help.

Comment: Your sample sheet looks like it's working. Sorry, your answer is somewhere in the syntax of the query formula. Strip it down to simplify if you have to. Keep in mind you have to use single quotes for string in a query function (i.e. 'July' while the entire query function is also string with double quotes. Confusing at first, but not too hard when you recognize it.  Hope it works.

Comment: Just to follow up for anyone that reads this in the future.  It is definitely working, I made a mistake on the underlying sample data.  @PGSystemTester, thank you very much for the awesome help.